# Problem with multiple OpenID accounts on Careers 2.0

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, openid

I recently received an invitation to Careers 2.0. I created an account, but accidentally logged in using a Google OpenID that I don't normally use and which was not linked to my Stack Overflow account (thanks, Autofill. Not.)

I started filling out my profile, and then discovered that no Stack Exchange sites were linked to my account. I realised I'd logged in using the wrong OpenID. I then tried adding the OpenID to my Stack Overflow account. I did that about 24 hours ago and it hasn't made any difference.

I then tried logging in to Careers 2.0 with my usual Stack Overflow ID and it logged me in, but seemingly to a different account without profile access.

It seems I have two accounts on Careers 2.0, and the wrong one is linked to Stack Overflow!

I tried adding the Stack Overflow OpenID to my Careers 2.0 profile, but when I do it logs me out of that account and into the one that has no access. This is, of course, frustrating.

How can I resolve this? I would like to either cancel the non-functional account or merge the accounts in some way.

**Update**:
My accounts are now merged, however I can't associate any stack exchange network sites with my account, so my Stack Overflow reputation isn't recognized. Any ideas?

Comment: A developer should be able to merge your accounts. I've added the "careers" tag to help ensure that it falls into capable hands.

Answer (score 2):

I found two accounts for you and have merged them. Your SE accounts should show up within 24hrs.

Comment: Thanks. My accounts are now merged, however I can't associate any stack exchange network sites with my account, so my Stack Overflow reputation isn't recognized. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm also experiencing issues with my Careers 2.0 profile. I have 2 openid's, but the one I almost never use is the one that shows my profile. The other one, which I use on stackexchange, seems to have an empty profile (clicking 'profile' doesn't send me to the profile page, but to some FAQ)

Comment: I have the same problem. I recently merged my two Stack Overflow profiles (merging a gmail.com ID account onto this corfield.org one). I expected all associated "stack" features to have been merged, including Careers. Today I got a recruiter message on the gmail.com account - and it seems the merge did not copy over the Careers profile and I can't associate the other Google OpenID with it so I'm stuck.